# Kio estas la diferenco inter "kreaĵo" kaj "verko"?

Tags: word-usage

Jen la difino de PIV pri [verko](http://vortaro.net/#verko):

> - 1 *Arta aŭ scienca produkto*: koniĝas majstro laŭ sia verkoZ; la fino
>     kronas la verkonZ; miaj lastaj tradukitaj verkojZ; ĝi estas verko, kiu
>     traktas pri unu el la aktualaj sociaj demandojZ; verko de antaŭ longe
>     mortinta klasikuloZ; mi legis ĉiujn verkojn de Z.; la verkoj de
>     DanteB.
> - 2 *(f) Rezulto de agado*: tiu malordo estas la verko de
>     fremdulojB; la popolo forgesis, ke ĉiuj verkoj de Herhor estis nur
>     plenumo de la intencoj de la juna faraonoB; ili ŝajnigas, ke la atako
>     kontraŭ la temploj estas la verko de FenicianojB.

Do, libro estas verko ĉar rezulto de la arto de skribado. Videoludo estas verko ĉar rezulto de diversaj artoj kaj sciencoj. Motoro estas verko ĉar rezulto de scienco.

Sed ĉiu homa kreaĵo estas rezulto de arto kaj de scienco, ĉu ne? Do ĉu la verkeco de iu kreaĵo venas de la intenco de la aŭtoro? Tiel, kreaĵoj kreitaj sen homa konscia intenco (kiel fekaĵoj aŭ montoj) ne estus verkoj.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La aferoj, kiujn oni povas nomi "kreaĵo" kaj "verko", estas plejparte samaj. Laŭ mi, ĉiu verko estas kreaĵo, sed ekzistas kreaĵoj (ekzemple multaj ne kreitaj de homoj) kiuj ne estas verkoj. Tamen, la vortojn mem oni uzas en malsamaj kuntekstoj, kaj ili kreas malsamajn tonojn:

- *Ĉi tiu rakonto estas verko de geniulo.*
- *Ĉi tiu rakonto estas kreaĵo de freneza strangulo.*

Aldone, oni ofte uzas *kreaĵon* por nomi tiujn aferojn kreitajn de Dio. La ekzemplo de PIV: *neniu kreaĵo estas por mi tiel abomena, kiel araneo*.

Mi diru ke ne ĉiu *verko* devas esti de homoj. Oni povas diri: *La Granda Kanjono estas verko de akvo, sablo, kaj tempo.* (pro la dua difino en via demando).

Answer (score 1):

Ŝajnas al mi, laŭ mia propra reserĉo, ke por nomi ion *verko*, ĝi devas necese esti skribinta. *Kreaĵoj* povas aparteni al aliajn kategoriojn. *Verkoj* estas *kreaĵoj*, sed *kreaĵoj* povas esti *verkoj* aŭ aliaj artaĵoj.